# FIFO cache vs LRU cache

Tags: caching, data-structures, hash, fifo

I'm really sorry for such simple question. I just want to be sure that I understand FIFO cache model correctly and I hope that someone will help me with that :) LRU cache deletes entry that was accessed least recently if the cache is full. FIFO deletes the entry that was added earlier(?) than other entries if the cache needs free space (for example if 'a' - 'v' - 'f' - 'k' is entries in the cache and 'a' is the oldest entry then cache will delete 'a' if it will need free space).

Am I right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are correct.

Think of FIFO as cars going through a tunnel.  The first car to go in the tunnel will be the first one to go out the other side.

Think of the LRU cache as cleaning out the garage.  You will throw away items that you have not used for a long time, and keep the ones that you use frequently.  An evolution of that algorithm (an improvement to simple LRU) would be to throw away items that have not been used for a long time, and are not expensive to replace if you need them after all.

Comment: An advantage of FIFO over LRU is that in FIFO, cache hits do not need to modify the cache. In LRU, every cache hit must also reposition the retrieved value to the front. We made good use of a FIFO cache in pyparsing's packrat parsing redesign, with only a small increase in cache misses.

Comment: Agree, though if the cached blocks are large, you can move an index to the cached data rather than the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LRU cache is based on least recent use of on object in cache but FIFO is based on the time an object is cached.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. FIFO means First In, First Out, i.e., consider (in this case delete) elements strictly in arrival order. LRU is Least Recently Used, the cache element that hasn't been used the longest time is evicted (on the hunch that it won't be needed soon).